# IntentService isn't starting

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service, android-intentservice

I have this `IntentService` inside a class. The intent service is not starting. What am i doing wrong?

```
public class getListOfUsersService extends IntentService {  
  public getListOfUsersService() {        
  super("DownloadListOfUsersIntentService");     
     System.out.println("intentService started");   
  }
 @Override  
  protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {    
   System.out.println("intentService onHandle started");           
    mService.sendMessage(Protocols.REQUEST_SEND_USER_LIST);
          while(true) {
                UserHolder UH = new UserHolder();
                String usersdata = mService.getString();
                System.out.println("userdata: "+ usersdata);
                String array[] = usersdata.split("<!!>");
                UH.setUserName(array[1]);
                UH.setUserPhoneNum(array[2]);
                userHolderList.add(UH);
                System.out.println("added to usersList");               
                if(isDone) break;
           }

      }
    }
```

I start it in a method :

```
public void update() {
    System.out.println("update");
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, getListOfUsersService.class);
    startService(intent);
}
```

I registered it in the Manifest:

```
 <service
        android:name=".getListOfUsersService"
        android:exported="false"/>
```

Comment: Your code seems fine and it dosn't shows any error.Are you trying to start it from a main thread does sys.out update shows in logcat or not ?

Comment: yes trying to start it from a method in the main thread. No nothing shows in the logcat.

Comment: It means that your update() method is not called thats why your service is not able to run make sure you are calling the right method or post the code from where you are calling update().

Comment: makovkastar's answer solved the problem. The update method was being called. I didnt know that the service should be static so that it works. didnt read that in the documentation . Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot have non-static inner Service class. If you want to have an inner Service class, declare it as static and specify it in manifest file:

```
<service android:name="com.my.package.OuterClass$InnerServiceClass" />
```

Comment: Your suggestion worked fine Thanks. I had a typo when first tried it.

Answer (score 0):

Is `<service ...>` a child of `<application...>` ? If it's not, it may be the problem.

One more suggestion is to use the context returned by *getApplicationContext()*, but that should not be thus important.

Comment: Yes it is a child.  `<application ...                                                                                                         <service
        android:name=".getListOfUsersService"
        android:exported="false"/>

    </application>`

Comment: Lacking better ideas, I would find a service tutorial in google (or download it from commonsware) and run it, and see what is different. Maybe I would start with the downloaded example and gradually change it to what it has to be -- and see with which change it stops working.

Comment: makovkastar's answer solved the problem. An inner class `InentService` should be declared as `static` and registered accordingly in the manfifest.